# Is it safe to edit .csproj file in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We have a C# solution with multiple projects. We are managing version control for the solution using Github desktop, i.e., outside Visual Studio. After pushing new code to GitHub on a new machine with a fresh install of Visual Studio 2019 community edition, when I add a new file to the API project in the solution, I find that the file gets added to the .csproj file as follows, and the IDE never includes the file in the build, debugging, code completion etc.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\TestController.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I also see a + sign next to the TestController file in Solution Explorer. Hovering over the + sign brings up the message "pending add."

Why is this happening? And is it safe to just remove this itemgroup block in the .csproj file? Is there a way to prevent this behavior for new files added to the project?

Details

Context:

C# solution with 5 projects - (1) WebAPI, (2) Identity, (3) DataAccess, (4) Services, (5) Shared libraries. Editing using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.

Full timeline:

1. Solution pulled from GitHub.com using GitHub desktop
2. Files added to DataAccess and Services project using Visual Studio. Everything was fine
3. New branch created in GitHub desktop. New files added to the branch using GitHub desktop and pushed to GitHub.com using GitHub desktop
4. Code merged with parent branch by project administrator
5. Local solution synced to remote repository using GitHub desktop

--- alert: problem seen now ---

6. New file (TestController) added to the API project using Visual Studio. This file does not become part of the build. IDE does not highlight ApiControllers, ControllerBase etc, does not indicate errors for mis-spelt services, pressing F11 on ApiControllers gives error message "cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret."
7. Google search suggests checking on .csproj file. Here I find that the new file is within the 'compile remove' block.

Comment: I don't know why that happens every time you craete a file, but yes it's safe to remove it.The "pending add" just means that you haven't commited the file to git.

Comment: _"New file (TestController) added to the API project using Visual Studio"_ -- please be even more specific. In a separate comment, you indicated that you do this by right-clicking on a _folder_, and adding an _item_. To understand the issue better, it would be good for you to be explicit about what kind of project this is exactly, what the relationship of the folder is to the project, and what the exact steps you use for adding the item are. Screen shots of the relevant parts of the UI as you go through the addition of this new item would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to edit .csproj file in Visual Studio 2019?

If you know what you're doing and you do it correctly, sure. Otherwise, not so much.

> Why is this happening? And is it safe to just remove this itemgroup block in the .csproj file? Is there a way to prevent this behavior for new files added to the project?

It's happening because a file showed up in the project subdirectory that Visual Studio doesn't have as part of that project. So it adds the `<Compile Remove... />` element to exclude it from being compiled as part of the project. It is safe to remove the element, but in my experience it just shows up again.

As a general rule, you should not be adding files to project directories managed by Visual Studio, except by using the Visual Studio UI itself. It's not clear from your post *why* you are doing this. The directory you apparently are adding files to is your *project* directory. It should only have files that do in fact belong to the project.

The best fix is to not try to add files to a project directory when they shouldn't be part of that project.

You may have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you can post a new question in which you explain the scenario in which you've added the files that don't belong, and ask for guidance to accomplish whatever broader goal it is you have, but without running afoul of Visual Studio's rules, you may get a better answer than "don't do that".

Comment: Thanks very much, sorry for forgetting to mention this detail. The file was added using the Visual Studio UI, i.e. right-clicking the controllers folder of the project in solution explorer, selecting add item, and adding the class. In other words, I am just adding a new Controller class in the usual way to the project, using the IDE's interface.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm still not clear exactly what you mean then by _"the IDE no longer includes the file in the build, debugging, code completion etc."_. The phrase _"no longer"_ suggests to me that the file _had_ been included previously. But you now seem to be saying the file is only just being added when this new element in the .csproj shows up. It would be helpful if you could edit your question to give a more detailed and precise timeline of the state of the project and the actions involved in changing that state.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have identified the problem. I believe what happened is that once the local branch was pushed to remote, further changes to the project made using Visual Studio were not being integrated into the project, even though I was not formally tracking the project in Visual Studio.

git status showed that I was still on my initial local branch. I did the following to sync with the remote parent branch and then start a new local branch:

```
git stash
git checkout <parent_branch>
git pull
git checkout -b <new_branch>
```

This switched me to a new branch, and now I am able to edit the file as usual.